# Error creating a variable in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to create a variable that holds the list of my locators and meshes in Maya. So I have this

```
locators = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'locator'), p=1)# Give me the list of locators
meshes = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'mesh'), p=1) #Give me the list of all meshes
```

But these only tend to work if there is a locator or polys available in the scene currently. Maya spits out an error:

```
line 1: Object [] is invalid
```

if there are no locators or poly found.

How can store them to work even if they are available in the scene or not? The purpose is to create search and replace tool. So the artist can search and replace only meshes if he/she wants to. But right now it errors out even when I am only S&R meshes. Locators give the error when I search for meshes and Meshes fail when I am looking for locators.

Below is my whole search and replace code:

```
def searchAndReplace(self):
    searchText = str(self.windowObj.myLookFor.text()) #My search text feild
    replaceText = str(self.windowObj.myRepFor.text()) #My replace text feild
    selection = cmds.ls(sl=True) #only selected items
    locators = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'locator'), p=1)# Give me the list of locators
    meshes = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'mesh'), p=1) #Give me the list of all meshes
    joints = cmds.ls(type = 'joint')# Give me the list of my joints.
    allObjects = locators, meshes, joints

    if len(selection) > 0:
        if self.windowObj.myRepAll.isChecked():
            print "All is selected"
            for object in meshes:
                if object.find(searchText) != -1:
                    newName = object.replace(searchText, replaceText)
                    cmds.rename(object, newName)
                    self.listofMeshes.append(meshes)
                else:
                    print "No mesh found. Skipping meshes"
            for object in locators:
                if object.find(searchText) != -1:
                    newName2 = object.replace(searchText, replaceText)
                    cmds.rename(object, newName2)
                    self.listofLocators.append(locators)
                else:
                    "No locators found. Skipping locators"
            for object in joints:
                if object.find(searchText) != -1:
                    newName3 = object.replace(searchText, replaceText)
                    cmds.rename(object, newName3)
                    self.listofJoints.append(joints)
                else:
                    print "No joints found. Skipping joints"
```

Need help in store the variables correctly so it can store locators, meshes and joints correctly and be able to use it if one of them is not available in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the two statements you pointed out in a new empty scene, I get a None on both of the variables.

In that case, before you start the loop, you could prevent the error by indenting each for loop into, for example, an **if meshes:**, or even better, an **if isinstance(meshes, list):**, which will only execute the code if meshes is a list:

```
if isinstance(meshes, list):
    for object in meshes:
        if object.find(searchText) != -1:
            newName = object.replace(searchText, replaceText)
            cmds.rename(object, newName)
            listofMeshes.append(meshes)
```

If you still get the same error when trying to execute the statements, indent that into a try/catch block to see a more detailed explanation on what's going on, and get more help from the [Maya CMDS' documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/listRelatives.html):

```
try:
    locators = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'locator'), p=1)

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

By default if `cmds.listRelatives` finds nothing instead of returning an empty `[]` like expected it will return `None`.

Two ways to fix this would be to either convert a `None` to a `[]`:

```
print cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'locator'), p=1) or []
> returns []
```

or do a condition check to see if the variable is empty:

```
sceneLocators = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'locator'), p=1)
if sceneLocators:
    print 'Continue'
else:
    print 'No locators!'
```

You should not wrap a `try` `except` like Carlos is suggesting. That is just bad practice in programming in general with some exceptions and usually a lazy way to go about things.